# Multiple forms in jsf page

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Here is my view

```
 <h:body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="upload">
        <h:form id="frmMain" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p:inputTextarea id="text" style="width: 99%" value="#{uploadfile.content}"  placeholder="What are you thinking?"></p:inputTextarea>
            <p:fileUpload auto="true" oncomplete="input()"  id="fileIdPhoto"  previewWidth="200" style="width: 100%" messageTemplate="{name}" fileUploadListener="#{uploadfile.upload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true"
                          multiple="true" update="messages"   allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"  />
            <p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
            <p:menubar  autoDisplay="false">
                <p:menuitem  />
                <f:facet name="options">
                    <p:commandButton  value="Publish" update="fileIdPhoto"  icon="ui-icon-extlink" actionListener="#{uploadfile.uploadPhoto}">
                    </p:commandButton>

                </f:facet>
            </p:menubar>
        </h:form>

    </div>
    <div id="body">
        <div id="post_container">

            <ul>
                <ui:repeat value="#{image.allpost}" var="value">
                    <h:form id="form">
                        <li>
                            <div id="post">               
                                <p:commandButton rendered="false" id="dynaButton" process="@this,form" value="Show" type="button" icon="ui-icon-extlink"/> cant not trigger it so I set render false 
                                <p:menu overlay="true" trigger="dynaButton" my="left top" at="left bottom">
                                    <p:submenu label="Ajax">
                                        <p:menuitem value="Delete" icon="ui-icon-disk"/>
                                        <p:menuitem value="Update" icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w"/>
                                    </p:submenu>
                                </p:menu>

                                <b>#{value.content}</b> <br/>
                                #{value.createtime} <br/>
                                <br />
                                <p:galleria value="#{image.getImgByID(value.id)}" rendered="#{not empty image.getImgByID(value.id)}" var="a" panelWidth="720" panelHeight="400" showCaption="true">
                                    <h:graphicImage value="data:image/jpeg;base64,#{a.imgUrl}"  style="width:100%;height:100% " alt="Image Description for #{a.imgName}" title="#{a.imgName}"/>
                                </p:galleria>
                                <p:rating value="#{value.rating}" stars="10" cancel="false"/>cant change those stars by clicking on it
                            </div>
                            <div id="post_ceperator"/>
                        </li>    
                    </h:form>
                </ui:repeat>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</h:body>
```

What I am trying to do is change the value of `p:rating` tag and `p:menu` to trigger but its seem like my page is only submitting the first form. Also how can I submit a post and div that contains my post will automatically update?

Comment: which command button should update the rating?

Comment: i am going to add onRate att on the view to catch event when stars are changed, but i can't change those stars any help

Comment: You can not submit the data of two form with one submit button. the submit button process just the data of his owner form.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the problem is that your components inside of the ui:repeat have all the time the same id's for each iteration.

The way i used to define ids in loops like that was to add some sort of unique prefix or suffix to them based on some field of the data over which i am iterating:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{image.allpost}" var="value">
       <h:form id="form_#{value.id}">
          <li>
             <div id="post_#{value.id}">
```

Now each of your components, including the form, which is highly likely to be the cause of your problem, will have its unique id for each of the loop repetition.

Comment: thats weird, they are separate forms.. also is your bean viewscoped? and do other input elements of that form work?